# How do you create a Rakefile?

Tags: ruby, rakefile

I have been creating a Rakefile. The directions says to create a Rakefile file that will help you automate common tasks. It also said to put in :

```
    require 'rake/testtask'

    Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
      t.libs << "tests"
      t.test_files = FileList['tests/test*.rb']
      t.verbose = true
    end
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: How do I create a rakefile?

Comment: Well, you create it. Same way as any other file.

Comment: You open your text editor, write the code, and save it as `rakefile`.

Comment: Thanks to you guys all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the file Test.rake and put it in your lib/task file

Answer (score 5):

You are going to want to keep your rake tasks in lib/tasks/your_task.rake

```
task :your_task => :environment do
    some code
end
```

your_task being the name of your rake task.

Hope this helps

Comment: What is `:environment` for?

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a new file and name it as task.rake. Normally we put the rake task in directory lib/tasks. But you can put it anywhere you like.

Answer (score 2):

create a file and name it TEST.rake in your lib/task file.